# JUnit define default timeout for category of tests

Tags: java, junit

Let's say I have a FastUnitTests category and I use these annotations to have a test to belong to it:

```
@Category(FastUnitTests.class)
@Test(timeout = 100)
public void something() {
    ...
}
```

I would like to enforce a timeout to every test that is categorized as a fast unit tests. What I need to do, even if I do not explicitly define the timeout:

```
@Category(FastUnitTests.class)
@Test
public void something() {
    ...
}
```

I still to have it set, just because of the category annotation.

Comment: Did you get any answer? It is not directly related, but a nice thing around the Junit Categories => this is a way to [compute 'Tests by Category' counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778167/10524205).

Comment: I managed to do it with creating CategoryTimeout rule that inherits Timeout rule, but checks for category annotation and sets the timeout. Unfortunately, I did not find a reliable way to get the time the test took. It seems that junit adds to the time of the test all the initializations, and this makes the whole thing very unreliable. ... I am not using it.